# Declaring rng('shuffle','twister') many times through the use of functions degrade computation time

Tags: matlab, function, random

I have an optimization program where I have a main program and three subprograms (functions) in MATLAB. I declared `rng('shuffle','twister')` in my main program but I thought that I needed to declare the same `rng('shuffle','twister')` under my functions since they also use random sampling. My question is if it is necessary to declare `rng('shuffle','twister')` in my functions since it greatly degrades the computation time. I seem to be getting the same answers anyway. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to repeatedly run [`rng(...)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) in your functions, just once when you start MATLAB if you want to get different numbers each time. The random number functions in MATLAB (i.e. `rand`, `randn`, `randi`, etc.) [share a global/system-wide generator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/managing-the-global-stream.html), so there is no need to reseed it except when you restart MATLAB.

> Since all of these functions access the same underlying stream, a call to one affects the values produced by the others at subsequent calls.

Hence, numbers generated in the different functions and in repeated calls to the functions will be different whether or not you reseed the generator.

---

More about the `'shuffle'` option from [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/controlling-random-number-generation.html), which indicates that not only is it not useful to re-seed frequently, but it may actually be undesirable from a statistical standpoint:

> 'shuffle' is a very easy way to reseed the random number generator. You might think that it's a good idea, or even necessary, to use it to get "true" randomness in MATLAB. For most purposes, though, it is not necessary to use 'shuffle' at all. Choosing a seed based on the current time does not improve the statistical properties of the values you'll get from rand, randi, and randn, and does not make them "more random" in any real sense. While it is perfectly fine to reseed the generator each time you start up MATLAB, or before you run some kind of large calculation involving random numbers, it is actually not a good idea to reseed the generator too frequently within a session, because this can affect the statistical properties of your random numbers.

Comment: Practically, how frequent is too frequent? (once per seconds/minutes/hours?)